# How can i insert a variable in a dictionary created with a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, class, dictionary

I would like to save the variable `x` in the dictionary and consequently print it for each element of the loop.

I use this code `test[row[0]].score_home.append(x)`. I would like to insert it as the last value (right after score_away=[]).

P.S: I don't want to store multiple values of x in the dictionary. Each match has an x. Each x has only one value (only 1)

I get this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`

```
{'Minnesota-Vegas': Info_Matchs(championship='NHL', date=8.1, current_round=9, clock='15:00', score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5], score_away=[])
```

I would like to get this output as a result:

```
{'Minnesota-Vegas': Info_Matchs(championship='NHL', date=8.1, current_round=9, clock='15:00', score_home=[0, 1, 1, 5], score_away=[], x=1.75)
```

Code

```
test = {}

@dataclass
class Info_Matchs:
    championship: str
    date: float
    round: int
    clock: str
    score_home: list[int]
    score_away: list[int]
    x: float

db = cursor_test.execute('''SELECT Next.team_home||"-"||Next.team_away, Next.tournmant,
                                                  Next.date, Next.round, Next.time,
                                                  Results.score_home
                                           FROM Next
                                           INNER JOIN Results
                                           ON Next.team_home = Results.team_home;''')
    

for row in db.fetchall():
    if row[0] not in test:
        info = Info_Matchs(
            championship=row[1],
            date=row[2],
            current_round=row[3],
            clock=row[4],
            score_home=list(),
            score_away=list(),
            x=None)

        test[row[0]] = info
    test[row[0]].score_home.append(row[5])

#HERE
for key, value in test.items():
    calc = sum(value.score_home)

    test[row[0]].x.append(calc)

    print(test)
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you expect your output to look like? You `append` to a list, so it makes sense to me that the value would get appended to the end of a list. Based on your description, it sounds like you're expecting the list to contain a dictionary key called `x`, which doesn't really make sense. Do you have example *desired* output you can show us?

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo I changed the code in the question while you were writing the comment. Now I've updated the question again, adding the desired output. Thank you

Comment: There seems to be some confusion between the code you're showing and the exception messages. The code shows `test[row[0]].x.append(x)`, but `x` is not a list, it's `None`, which is consistent with the exception. However, your reported exception messages talk about `score_home` which should be a list. Can you verify you're getting the message you show with the code you've given?

Comment: @Blckknght I checked. I still get the same error. But I changed my code, I had called both x. I have now replaced it with calc. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: I was referring to the `x` you didn't change. What do you expect `test[row[0]].x` to be, just before you `append` to it?

Comment: @Blckknght Ah ok. If you look a few lines above, I did the same thing with test[row[0]].score_home.append(row[5]). This way, earlier, I added score_home. Now I wanted to do the same thing with x, but instead of row[5] there is the variable calc

Comment: The issue isn't with the value you're computing, it's with what is in the object already. When you create the object, its `score_home` attribute is set to an empty list. The `x` attribute on the other hand, is `None`. You can't append to `None`, which is exactly what the exception message is telling you. It's not really clear to me what you want to do instead. Maybe `test[row[0]].x = calc`? (Or, actually, now that I look at it, the `test[row[0]]` part is suspect too, since you're not looping over `row`s any more, but `key, value` pairs. Try `value.x = calc`!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
info = Info_Matchs(
    championship=row[1],
    date=row[2],
    current_round=row[3],
    clock=row[4],
    score_home=list(),
    score_away=list(),
    x=None)
```

Here you are assigning x as `None` value and then you're trying to treat that `None` value as a `list` by appending to it.

Instead of doing this:

```
test[row[0]].x.append(calc)
```

Assign a new value to the `x`:

```
test[key].x = calc
```

Comment: I tested your code. test[row[0]].x = calc doesn't work. Instead it works correctly if I write test[key].x = calc. But I didn't understand one thing: did you write me 2 different solutions? Can you better split and separate the two solutions please? Currently I wrote x=[] and then wrote test[key].x = calc. I don't understand your other solution. Thank you

Comment: The last solution was for if you were to append to the variable `x`. In that case you must initialize it as an empty list to start. But You can ignore it if it's not what you want.

I wasn't sure about `row[0]` and you did not speak anything about it so I left it as it is.

Comment: @Takao貴男 But yes, As it is a `dictionary` and you're iterating through its `key` and `values`  logically change the `test[row[0]]` to `test[key]`. But let me know if that's not what you want.

Comment: I assigned a new value to x like so test[row[0]].x = calc. Then I started as an empty list x=[]. I was wrong? Can you edit your answer and better split the two solutions? I will be happy to accept your answer. Thank you

Comment: Ok, there are two ways with test[row[0]].x.append(calc) or with test[key].x = calc. I understood this. Instead, I didn't understand x=None or x=[] that you wrote before and now you deleted it

Comment: That was for if you wanted to use `x` as a list; Then you should have given it a `[]` value instead of `None`. But it appeared to have confused you and so I deleted it as it was not really helping any much.